# jQueryUi's drag binding way to slow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

So jCrop is very fast, but when doing a similar implementation with jQueryUi's draggable(), and binding it, it goes very slow and jiterish: http://jsfiddle.net/LNdPJ/5/

How can I remedy the situation?